# What is the best practice with vuejs store (pinia here) and api platform GET / POST operation?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, symfony, api-platform.com, pinia

Im trying to figure out what could be the best conception for my case or if i do not know something that could provide an "automatic" way to do it.

So im using Symfony 6 / Api platform as backend.
Im using Vuejs 3 + pinia + typescript enable as frontend app. (Im newbie on front)
So here is my workcase.
Assuming i have a class Company.php

```
class Company
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    private int $id;

    #[Slug(fields: ["name"])]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    private string $slug;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read', 'company:write'])]
    private string $name;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Address::class, cascade: ["persist", "remove"])]
    #[Groups(['read', 'company:write'])]
    private Address $address;
}
```

Which has relation with Address

```
class Address
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    private int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read', 'write', 'company:write'])]
    private string $address;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read', 'write', 'company:write'])]
    private string $zipCode;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Country::class)]
    #[Groups(['read', 'write', 'company:write'])]
    private Country $country;
}
```

And has relation with Country which is a basic Country class

On my Hydra i have this for output :

```
{
      "@context": "string",
      "@id": "string",
      "@type": "string",
      "id": 0,
      "slug": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "address": {
        "@context": "string",
        "@id": "string",
        "@type": "string",
        "id": 0,
        "address": "string",
        "zipCode": "string",
        "country": {
          "@id": "string",
          "@type": "string",
          "@context": "string",
          "id": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "slug": "string",
          "currencyCode": "string",
          "code": "string"
        }
      }
}
```

And this for input

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "address": {
    "address": "string",
    "zipCode": "string",
    "country": "string" (IRI to provide here like "/api/countries/2")
  },
}
```

So on my side, everything is correctly set up here.
When i GET company i want to get all information about his nested object.
And when i PUT/PATCH a company i want to block edition on some nested object.
Im my case i do not want to be able to edit Country name when editing a company.
It work.

My conception issue come on the front side (which is new for me).
When i use api platform https://api-platform.com/docs/create-client/typescript/
It generate this file :

```
export interface Company {
  "@id"?: string;
  name?: string;
  address?: any;
  readonly slug?: string;
}
```

As you can see address is type of any. And this is the interface i use in my CompanyStore (Pinia not Vuex)
I have a vuejs component form where i can edit a company which embed an address component like this one (i use vuetify).

```
<template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <v-text-field
        id="address"
        label="Address"
        v-model="item.address"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Address of the company"
    />
  <v-text-field
      id="zipCode"
      label="Zipcode"
      v-model="item.zipCode"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Zip code"
  >
  </v-text-field>
    <v-select
        v-model="item.country"
        :items="countries"
        item-title="name"
        item-value="@id"
        label="Country"
    >
    </v-select>
  </div>
</template>
```

My goal is simple, when i retrieve a company i have a FULL object with all details about nested relation. It help me to display "things" to frontend user.
But when i submit my company using a Pinia action i dont want to submit the "big" object to my api but an adapted object according to api platform input requirement (it does not work anyway).
For example, for country i just have to do :

```
"country": "api/countries/2"
```

i dont need something like:

```
"country": {
              "@id": "api/countries/2",
              "id": 2,
              "name": "France",
              "slug": "france",
              "currencyCode": "EUR",
              "code": "FR"
            }
```

Is there a best practice to transform that api output to my api input requirement object on pinia store / vuejs3 side ?

Thanks for everyone who read it and i am sorry if there is anything confusing or using "bad word" for some concept.

Comment: May not specific to Pinia or stores. It's a common problem with populated db fields. If you don't have problems with storing `country` object instead of its id, then the only place that needs to be specially treated is when you send data, you can do transforms like `let companyDto = {...company, country: company.country['@id'] }`

Comment: @EstusFlask it seems like a great and simple solution which is typically the kind of answer i was looking for because of a lack of knowledge from my side. Thanks a lot, i'm gonna try it.

Comment: Could you provide me a "documentation" about this kind of array management.  Seems like something basic in javascript but i don't know "which" word to type to find example.

Comment: Don't have a specific source. This is not specific to JS. Basically this is depopulation, since `country` field that you receive from back end has been already populated. "it does not work anyway" - could be fixed for compatibility reasons on back end but it's preferable to send id only just because it's more efficient.

Comment: The alternative way that is specific to a store is that you can keep relations at front end, by receiving `country` unpopulated and mapping country ids to an object from a list of countries in Pinia `getter`. This optimization makes sense when there's a bunch of records (1000s of them) that use a limited set of records from another collection (countries). If companies are stored this way, you won't have the problem with data being sent in denormalized form (shouldn't be a determining factor)

Comment: It look like i will haveto do Company.ts for output and CompanyDto.ts input interface no matter what and a function that transform the first into an other for a complex case.
I concentrated my example on country field but i have the same problem with a list of associated user.